# count the type of number in an array - functional javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

This is a program I came up with that counts the type of numbers i.e whether its positive, negative or zero. Is it possible to write this code in functional javascript using any of array methods like reduce, map, filter? Prefer the output to be in array format.

```
var array= [-1,1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
var positive_count = 0, negative_count = 0;
var zero_count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    if (array[i] > 0)
        positive_count += 1;
    else if(array[i] < 0)
       negative_count += 1
    else
      zero_count+= 1;
}

console.log (positive_count + "," + negative_count+ "," + zero_count);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CpHg1gMX0Oao4PQVd08g?p=preview

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you tried it? Please show us your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to do this:

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/povene/4/edit?js,console)

```
var count = array.reduce(function(a, b){
  if (b < 0) {
    a.negative = ++a.negative || 1;
  }  
  if (b === 0) {
    a.zero = ++a.zero || 1;
  }  
  if (b > 0) {
    a.positive = ++a.positive || 1;
  }
  return a;
}, {});
```

[MDN Docs on reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

You could also use `.filter` and get the lengths:

```
var z = array.filter(function(e) {
  return e === 0;
}).length;

var p = array.filter(function(e) {
  return e > 0;
}).length;

var n = array.filter(function(e) {
  return e < 0;
}).length;
```

Comment: Is the output in array format possible using this technique? like [count of positive, count of negative, count of zero].

Comment: In your `reduce` sample you should start with `{negative:0, zero:0, positive:0}` instead of an empty object. That way you'll get the correct results even when the array is empty, and you don't need those defaults after the increments.

Comment: I was trying to get it working with one array.filter...may be that is not possible ..

Answer (score 0):

neelmeg.  In your script for loop you iterate over the array only while i < 10, but your array contains 12 elements so your result will be wrong.

Yes, it is possible to perform this in a more functional way using reduce ...

```
const ary = [-1,1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

const result = ary.reduce((acc, v) => {
  return v > 0
    ? [(acc[0] + 1), acc[1], acc[2]]
    : v < 0
      ? [acc[0], (acc[1] + 1), acc[2]]
      : [acc[0], acc[1], (acc[2] + 1)]
}, [0, 0, 0])

console.log(result)
```

This will return an array in the form [+ numCount, - numCount, zero count]
 => [ 9, 1, 2 ]